# How to connect my android application with mongodb (mongolab)

Tags: android, json, mongodb, mlab

I am new to `mongodb`, now I need to connect `mongodb` with my android application. And also I am using my `mongodb` in `mongolab`.

In `mongolab` website I can't see option called "`View JSON Objects`", but when I saw any YouTube videos related to `mongolab` they were having that option. The website might be updated, so I can't get JSON objects separately from the website, and also I tried to pass that URL from my application. I can't get the JSON data.

Finally, I need to connect my android application to `mongodb` (`mongolab`) through URL request and then process the JSON data.

Comment: you need to create REST services to connect to the mongodb

Answer (score 2):

You will have to develop REST APIs for connecting to MongoDB. The application server connects to the MongoDB and run query on MongoDB using ORMs.

If you want to connect to a database service directly without REST API, you could you mBAAS like Parse (https://parse.com/) or Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/) and connect directly to a database but not MongoDB.

Comment: Note that parse.com is in the process of shutting down

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yup. Thanks for adding that point. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write REST API for accessing data in MongoDB.
You can write this REST interface in language of your choice.
There are couple REST frameworks available: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/